# Install Windows Phone 7 on Android MyTouch 3g?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

I have a MyTouch 3G running Android, which has been rooted. I was wondering if it is possible to install Windows Phone 7 on this phone, or if it is even close to compatible.

Thanks

Comment: My question with this is why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No.

**Long answer:**

Not without (as far as I'm aware) writing and customizing a ton of drivers and system bits that are necessary for the Windows platform to work on that specific phone. To be honest, it's unlikely that Windows Phone 7 will be ported to Android handsets, even with the greatest of hackers attempting it. *Not saying it's impossible, just unlikely.*

Comment: Adam,
Makes sense. Probably the only hope in this port is that fact that HTC makes the MyTouch, and Windows Phone 7 Hardware. Hopefully that will help out on the driver front. But I'm with you on this being unlikely.  There doesn't really seem to be much clamor for this.

Comment: The drivers are already there you just need to convert them from Linux to windows, or figure some way to wrapper .so libs into .dlls

Comment: That would take an incredible amount of work, simply because Linux drivers and Windows drivers interact with their respective operating systems in such different ways. Years of reverse-engineering would be required.